# Further knowledge about Interface in C#

Tags: c#, interface

Can someone give me a concrete example and explanation how to implement interface. I'm just a beginner to this.

Comment: This question's format is inappropriate for Stack Overflow.  Why don't you give a code example of what you've tried so far and what you've found confusing?

Comment: 'further knowledge about interface in c#', and you tagged android and java ?

Comment: *further knowledge* means you have studied and understood at least something already. What is it? Ask a specific question! Else you are not going to get answer, but down votes for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My article on interfaces will be able to provide you with a better understanding on interfaces - [Click here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/804581/Why-do-we-need-Interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are very useful. When you implement an interface, you are suggesting that the implementing class "can be used as" something. For example, the `Int32` struct implements `IComparable<int>`. Which means that when there is a method that requires an argument of type `IComparable<int>`, you can use an int!

But how do you prove that your class can be used as something? You look at the interface declaration and say, oh the `IComparable<int>` interface needs a `compareTo` method! Then you write a `compareTo` method in your class. That way, your class has proven that it can be used as `IComparable<int>`.